# How do I add a post_filter to an ElasticSearch query using C# NEST client?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

In simple terms, I have this query:

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "query_string": {
               "query": "my_query_text"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "post_filter": {
      "term": {
         "topics": [
            "top1",
            "top2"
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "authors": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "authors"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

which I want to replicate using the C# NEST client.

I can't find a way of adding a post_filter in the NEST client though?

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ***SearchDescriptor*** it is referred to by method ***"Filter"*** instead of ***PostFilter***.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/997) in github with regard to naming it more appropriately which most probably will be fixed in 2.0.